# Oracle SQL Update getting stuck

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I am using this query:

```
UPDATE tbl_temp SET KEYVALUE =
(
   WITH PRIMARKY_KEYS AS (
          SELECT listagg(colvalue,'|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY idcolumn) AS colvalues,idnum  
          FROM tmp_columns
          WHERE tmp_columns.columnname IN ('ID','IDSCHEME')
          GROUP BY idnum
   )
   SELECT colvalues FROM PRIMARKY_KEYS P
   WHERE tbl_temp.id_row = P.idnum
);
```

but it just gets stuck

tbl_temp has these columns:

```
id_row number
test_env char(3)
tablename varchar2,
rowvalue  varchar2 ,
uniquekey varchar2
keyvalue varchar2
```

tmp_columns has these columns:

```
idnum number
env varchar2
colvalue
idcolumn
columnname
```

Comment: Do you have example data for both tables, preferably as INSERT statements?

Comment: What does 'gets stuck' mean - fails, or appears to hang? Do you have uncommitted changes to `tbl_temp` in another session?

Comment: @user2501620 - if it hangs indefinitely, that is often a hint that you have uncommitted data. Have you populated `tbl_temp` in another session/client, or run a version of the update somewhere else and not rolled that back before trying again?

Comment: But can we optimize this query to perform better ?